# How can I connect to my home VNC server via its hostname?

Tags: remote-access, vnc

<sup>as asked in the Android [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1522466#1522466).</sup>

At home I have a remote-access VNC server set up (running UltraVNC server). My current Android VNC app, called, funnily enough `androidVNC` will only accept IP addresses to connect to. This is fine when using it inside the home, but as I want to access it from outside, my external IP address is dynamic, so when I save the settings one day it may be different the next day.

I have a domain, `home.example.co.uk` that is set up for the web server also running on that machine. If I open the ports in my home router, how can I connect via the server hostname (`home.example.co.uk:5900`, or similar)? If it requires a new VNC client, so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android VNC viewer](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) is free and works with host names, but I have not played around with it much, so I cannot vouch for quality. Alternatively you could use a hostname to ip resolver (either as an app or as a [website](http://www.ipchecking.com/)) to find out the ip address and use that to connect. I just tried out DNS Lookup from the Android market, and it looks like a pretty decent solution (fast, long-press to copy ip).

If you have the time, send an email to the creator of the app you use for a feature request, I'm sure he would appreciate the feedback :).

Comment: This is the one I've been using, although I've been unable to get it to work with hostnames...might be something on my end though, as it does say you can do it in the documentation.

Comment: Very strange, I had tried it myself with a host name to make sure it works. Perhaps it is a DNS issue? Can you access the http server on your machine (or use SSH, ping, any other service) by host name from your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exposing your VNC server to the internet, consider using a VPN. This would secure and encrypt your remote connection. And as a side-benefit, you could save the internal IP address in your Android VNC client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think it should work with [VNC Viewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android) (paid app but worth its price).

I'll give it a try when I'm at home and edit the answer.